# What is this vim functionality?

Tags: linux, vim

When using vim and not typing for like 5-10 seconds this automatically pops up at the bottom of the 

editor window:

```
  1:   34 done
  2:   93         done
  3:   94     done
  4:  110     done
  5:  262                     done
  6:  263                 done
  7:  376                         done
  8:  381                     done
  9:  400 done
 10:  420                 done
 11:  453                 done
 12:  493                 done
 13:  523             done
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I didnt press anything to get this up and i dont know why its happening. This means that when im reading the code to check if there are any errors etc im getting thos annoying message that im not even sure what is popping up or what kind of information it is suppose to be, im not pressing any key combination to get it up, it just shows up taking up like 20% of the vim window, and sometimes there is even more lines of code that just pops up like that with line numbers and i dont understand why.

Has anyone seen anything like this and knows how to turn it off or knows why it popping up or why its trying to tell me ? Seems like a wierd functionality to have. My vimrc file is default since im using the editor on a server at the moment by i have seen this happening several other places.

Comment: You have a broken plugin.

Comment: hmm ok, how can i identify which plugin is broken ? And, can someone explain the -1 to me, how was i suppose to google this when there is no error message or anything. dont really care about the -1 though, just think its really wierd.

Comment: Disable them one at a time, see where this stops happening. Or if you have a lot, you might want to try a binary search.

Comment: -1 might be a little harsh, but the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as the question is about software, not programming.

Comment: @user2959896 do a "binary search" to locate the problematic plugin.

Comment: @chepner, the question is about _software tools commonly used by programmers_ which is perfectly on topic (See the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). My guess is that the -1 is due to lack of effort in identifying the problem. For example, I would have expected the OP to have mentioned what plugins he has installed, if he has tried disabling them and so on, showing why he couldn't solve the problem on his own.

Comment: I could have mentioned that, but im using vim on a central server which doesnt have any specific vimrc file, it only uses the default from the installation (if any) and no additonal plugins from what i know, but ill take a closer look. The second reason is that i didnt know by looking at that text that it was related to a problem with a plugin since it doesnt say anything about it and i have never installed plugins on it either.

Comment: Are they actually inserted in your buffer or can you get rid of them with `<C-l>`? These messages look a lot like the output of some backgrounded command.

Answer (score 0):

you definitely have a broken plugin, which, my guess, is binding something on `CursorHold`. To debug your vim session, you can launch vim using:

```
vim -V9vim.log myfile
```

and look at the log file for what's being done. Look for the `CursorHold` string within it.

You can list all the scripts you've loaded using:

```
:scriptnames
```

to show you what scripts you're using and make guesses to which one can be the faulty one. Then, you start vim with:

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE
```

to have it load no vimrc config file, and then launch your config files, scripts manually by taking the vim.log and the scriptnames' output as references. And finally, you can inspect startup time to look at what your vim is loading and how much time it takes using:

```
vim +q --startuptime startuptime.txt
```

references:

- http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/debugging-vim-setup/
- http://www.euperia.com/development/debugging-your-vimrc/416

Comment: thanks for a good description, i will try that. there is no vimrc file except the default one coming with the installation (if any) and shouldnt be any additonal plugins either except those who are coming with the installation.

Comment: then, there may be a program running in the background doing some output in your shell. Try listing any background process using `jobs`.

Comment: There are jobs running in cron every 15 minutes in addition to some other jobs.. they might not be coded good enough and might output to the shell or terminal, would that be something that could trigger this behaviour ? The file im working on has however nothing to do with these cronjobs and in theory the cronjobs are running without being attached to any terminal ("?" as terminal in the ps output)

Comment: I can't tell, your problem is most likely a setup problem on your system, and there are too many factors unknown to me. Are you running it in text console? Are you connecting using ssh or telnet? Are you running a terminal emulator? Would the terminal emulator try to run things on your behalf? Are you using a terminal multiplexer (like screen or tmux)? Are your login scripts launching background processes? etc… You asked about vim, I gave you the way to debug vim or *know* whether it's vim's fault or not. If that happens with `vim -u NONE -U NONE`, then look for something else!